# What is the correct way to work with transactions with NestJs and TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS with TypeORM. I have several modules and each module contain service. There are some modules that import other modules and use their services.

```
// In Person Module
@Injectable()
class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}

  public async deleteUsersByCompany(companyId: string) {
    const usersToDelete = await this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('user.companyId = :companyId', { companyId })
      .getMany();

    if (usersToDelete.length > 0) {
      await this.usersRepository.delete(
        usersToDelete.map((user) => user.id),
      );
    }
  }

  ...
}

// Company Module

@Injectable()
class CompanyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Company)
    private companysRepository: Repository<Company>,
    private usersService: UserService
  ) {}

  public async deleteCompany(companyId: string) {
    const companyToDelete = await this.companysRepository.find(companyId);

    if (companyToDelete) {
      await usersService.deleteUsersByCompany(companyToDelete.id)
      await this.companysRepository.delete(companyToDelete);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

In this example:

1. I want `usersService.deleteUsersByCompany` to be atomic operation
2. I want `companyService.deleteCompany` to be atomic operation
3. Both `usersService.deleteUsersByCompany` and `companyService.deleteCompany` can be triggered by the user

I want to wrap both actions in transaction. I've read [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#transactions) and [TypeOrm documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions) but couldn't find an answer how to do this properly.
The main thing here is that `usersService.deleteUsersByCompany` is being called by `companyService.deleteCompany`.

1. How can I support such "nested transactions"?
2. Does QueryRunner replace the Repository pattern?
3. Should my services hold both Repository and Connection instances? Repository for non-transactional operations and connection to get QueryRunner?

Comment: You need those methods to also be executable outside of a transaction context?

Comment: Yes. Those methods can be used anywhere.

Comment: I have the knowledge but not the time, I'll try to write an answer tomorrow. Meanwhile - what you need is to pass an optional param to the methods: `entityManager` you can get it from the transaction method you choose (all the api's of typeorm, includnig the decorator) `deleteUsersByCompany(companyId: string, entityManager: EntityManager = this.usersRepository.manager)` inside the method: `entityManager.getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder('user') ...` it should be something like that, I'll think of a prettier implementation.

Comment: I already know that. The thing is that refactor all the services to get another entityManager  parameter doesn't look good to me. It just ANY method that deals with the DB. In addition, in each method I have to check whether the transaction started or I should start a new one. It is a lot for a boilerplate to put in any method. Was trying `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` which sounds promising but it doesn't work well (https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked/issues/95) and cause other issues. I still looking for a proper solution.

Comment: I think I gave you a proper and working solution. If you're looking for abstractions, I would read the docs of custom repository. Either way you'll need to use a package or implement that logic yourself.

Comment: I agree with you and I already knew that idea. Unfortunately I don't think it is practical implementation without a proper abstraction. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I think you will need to make a custom repository to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use transaction is using the EntityManager API, check a simple example from a microservice:

```
import { WRITE_CONNECTION } from '@my-api/common';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { InjectEntityManager } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private logger = new Logger(MyService.name);
  constructor(
    @InjectEntityManager(WRITE_CONNECTION) private entityManager: EntityManager,
  ) {}

  async saveSomething(data: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      return await this.entityManager.transaction(async (entityManager) => {
        const firstRepository = entityManager.getCustomRepository(FirstRepository);
        const secondRepository = entityManager.getCustomRepository(SecondRepository);

        const firstRecord = firstRepository.create({ data });
        await firstRepository.save(firstRecord);

        const secondRecord = secondRepository.create({ data });
        await secondRepository.save(secondRecord);

        // Save entities directly
        await entityManager.save([...]);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(`Failed saving something, error ${error.message}`, error.stack);
      throw new RpcException(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, we use the entityManager for read and write operations in the same transaction that can execute a rollback automatically if any of these operations fails.

For more details check the repository of TypeORM with examples [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-manager-api.md).

So if you want to wrap both actions in the same transaction, you need to call a method and pass the repository as a parameter. e.g:

```
async findOneItem(
  itemId: number,
  myRepository: MyRepository = this.myRepository, // Optional parameter if needed
) {
  return await myRepository.findOne(itemId);
}
```